# Apex Replay Debugger Checkpoint Action Script

Tags: debugging, apex-debugger, apex-replay-debugger

There is a replay debugger checkpoint functionality named "Action Scripts" that appears to not be documented. I'd like to learn more outside of my own personal tinkering.

Can anyone link some documentation or provide some insight into the capabilities and use cases of this functionality?

My initial thought is that it allows us to inject scripts in the form of Apex or SOQL directly into the runtime at the target checkpoint without needing to modify the code. If that is the case then this is a pretty big deal and I'm shocked this functionality hasn't been hyped up more.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was privately sent this link via another channel. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_dev_console_checkpoints_overlaying_soql.htm&type=5

Comment: You should add some specific details here - link only answers are frowned upon since those links tend to break over time, so the answer becomes useless.